# Access on Sharepoint view

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have created a custom list with 4 columns and I have created two views, view1 and view2 for this list. Now I have 2 sharepoint groups, groups1 and group2. My requirement is that I want to restrict users from group1 to see items only in view1 and group2 to see items only in view2. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do some "audience targeting":

[Check this out](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/target-content-to-specific-audiences-HA010169053.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, but I try to set this, I get this error "No exact match was found. Click the item(s) that did not resolve for more options.". I am setting it with a sharepoint group. Please help.

Comment: Have you fixed it? I have been a little busy these days, but i'll gladly take a look at this error.